# Xcode 12 compiling bitcode takes forever (In-house build)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I have an in-house app and whenever I build it with "rebuild with bitcode" option it takes time. do I still need to enable the bitcode even if I will not upload it in the appstore? this is an in house build.
Are there any pros and cons whenever we build an in-house app with bitcode?

Comment: Actually you _never_ need to enable bitcode.

Comment: @matt why, are there any pros or cons?

Comment: Do you understand what bitcode is? In what way does it do something you need done?

Comment: Unless your build includes a WatchOS target. Then bitcode *is* required